# Использовать терминал с сессией через Ruby

Tags: linux, ruby, shell, terminal, exec

Ruby дает выполнять команды •Nix терминала через `System`, `Exec`, `Irb` и тд, но у меня не получается сохранить сессию между командами. То есть я открываю консольное приложение в нем через, например, `exec("./app")`, но внутренние команды исполнить не могу, как сделал бы это через обычную сессию `/bin/sh`.

```
# ./app
app> do_something
```

Вот этот `do_something` и "отпадывает".

Спасибо кто откликнется, может библиотеки знает по этой теме, всему рад.

UPD:
То есть у меня есть `./app` и внутри него мне надо исполнить ряд действий отлавливая вывод инфы и на ее основе слать команды дальше. А проблема, с которой я сталкиваюсь, это когда программа доходит до команды запуска приложения она перенаправляет меня в терминал и прерывается (ожидая завершения работы текущей программы), а мне нужно исполнить внутри открывшегося `./app` еще команды.

Comment: речь про сохранение истории выполненных команд?

Comment: Уточните, о какой "сессии" речь, да.

Comment: @D-side  Да, прошу прощения. Поправил

Comment: @alexanderbarakin поправил вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Читайте внимательнее документацию.

[`exec` делает "немножко" не то, что вы ожидаете](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-exec).

> Replaces the current process by running the given external command

...он замещает текущий процесс Ruby. То есть, на этой строчке **ваша программа завершается**, вместо неё ОС приклеивает процесс, который вы запустили.

Скорее всего, вам нужен [модуль `Open3`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html) из стандартной библиотеки, а конкретно методы `popen3` и/или `popen2`. Они запускают новый процесс, прицепив к его потокам стандартного IO подконтрольные Ruby потоки, а также создают отдельный `Thread`, который ждёт завершения процесса.

То, что вы вводили бы с клавиатуры, подавайте в полученный `stdin` нового процесса, и не забывайте читать его `stdout` и `stderr`, поскольку размер их буферов обычно ограничен, и их заполенность может повесить программу. В документации есть об этом детали.

Comment: Спасибо большое @D-side! Буду пробовать